# How to share the same viewModel between two views in extjs?

Tags: extjs, viewmodel

Is it possible that two or more views in extjs share the same viewModel?

For example, if I have two views as presented in the code below, both views do not have the same view model, but instances of that viewModel. Maybe that was intention, but how to achieve to have global field that would be accessible across several views with the same declaration for viewModel.

So, I would like to bind the field `name`, so the change in one view automatically causes changes in all corresponding views.

```
           Ext.define('MainModel', {
                extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
                alias: 'viewmodel.main',

                data: {
                    name : '',
                }
            });
            
            Ext.define('View1', {
                extend: 'Ext.Container',    
                xtype: 'view1',

                viewModel: {
                    type: 'main'
                },
                
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Name:',
                    bind: {
                        value: '{name}',
                    }       
                }
                    ]
            });
            
            Ext.define('View2', {
                extend: 'Ext.Container',    
                xtype: 'view2',

                viewModel: {
                    type: 'main'
                },

                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Name:',
                    bind: {
                        value: '{name}',
                    }       
                }
                    ]
                
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do this they way you are asking.  When you bind to a data element the system will first check the current components view model if it is does not find the value it will go up the parent and look and will continue this until it finds a match or there are no more parents.  So if you want to share data in a view model you should store the data in a parent viewModel.

Here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3b5s)

The fields have two way binding so as you type in one it will update the view model and then the other field will be updated.  On the fiddle edit each field and the other field will change. You can set either the property in the viewModel or either one of the two fields.

This [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3b5u) shows setting the value of the field and the data in the parent viewModel via a button.